# Can't Mount Databases in the Recovery Storage Group in Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

After restoring some mail stores, mounting them in the recovery storage group errors out.    So far a repair with eseutil (which the log says was successful) and a server reboot has been tried.  A defrag is currently running on the mail store

I need to go through this again to post the exact error codes, so I will be updating this question.  But I thought someone who does this a lot might have a "More times than not..." answer in the meantime.

```
An Internal Processing Error has occurented. Try restart the exchange ... (Nothing more useful here)
ID no: c1041724
Exchange System Manager
```

Events:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   MSExchangeIS
Event Category: General 
Event ID:   9519
Date:       4/13/2010
Time:       9:40:20 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   MAIL01
Description:
Error 0xfffff764 starting database "Recovery Storage Group\Denver" on the Microsoft Exchange Information Store. 

Data:
0000: 46 61 69 6c 65 64 20 74   Failed t
0008: 6f 20 61 74 74 61 63 68   o attach
0010: 20 74 6f 20 4a 65 74 20    to Jet 
0018: 44 42 00                  DB.
```

Event 2:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   MSExchangeIS
Event Category: General 
Event ID:   9518
Date:       4/13/2010
Time:       9:40:20 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   MAIL01
Description:
Error 0xfffff764 starting Storage Group .... CN=InformationStore/CN=Recovery Storage Group on the Microsoft Exchange Information Store. 
MDB failed to start.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you restored the EDB, did you restore the log chain and STM (as joeqwerty points out) as well?  I'm not 100% positive on how NetBackup does it's backups, but it probably uses VSS, which means that when the backup is taken, the EDB is in an inconsistent state.  A VSS backup will flush the cache to disk, but it doesn't roll the logs into the database.  When you're setting up the RSG and trying to mount the database, make sure that you have the EDB, STM, and logs from the same backup timestamp.  When you mount the database, the logs will be rolled into the EDB, bringing it to a consistent state, and it should mount.

Comment: STM file is there, but I didn't chose to restore the log files... But shouldn't the estutil after a hard recovery put it in a consistent state?

Comment: I would definitely start there then.  If you still have some problems mounting, try doing a fresh restore of EDB, STM, and logs and mounting that.  It's a possibility that running ESEutil against it modified it and invalidated the log chain (that's a long shot, but I'm just trying to think ahead).

Comment: @ your edit... Did you run ESEutil in hard recovery (/C)?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998075%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997478%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx.  I would try to do a soft recovery first using a fresh restore of the EDB, STM and logs first before doing a hard recovery.

Comment: I thought we did, but apparently talking to the exchange person he didn't, so that seems likely what could be wrong.

Comment: Did you follow the steps on page 61 here? : ftp://exftpp.symantec.com/pub/support/products/NetBackup_Enterprise_Server/279276.pdf

Comment: And... you should look at the last item on this page http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb795713.aspx

Answer (score 1):

EventID.net suggests that the problem might be a missing streaming file (.stm) for the DB in question.

Answer (score 0):

Use following steps to run Soft and Hard Recovery.

**Run Soft Recovery**

- First check log files should be in a Clean state:

  **Eseutil /ml “Path of the log files\log prefix”**
- If the log files are healthy, then perform the Soft recovery:

  **Eseutil/r  /l “Path of the log files” /d “Path of the database”**

  Once the command completes then mount the database

**Run HARD RECOVERY:**

- If log files are not in clean state or missing, then perform Hard recovery.

  **eseutil /p “D:\Exchsrvr\Mailbox Store (SERVER).edb”**
- Run OFFLINE DEFRAG: Once hard recovery finishes, you need to defrag the databases, for this, You must have space for hard disk equal to 110% size of the database that you want to defragment.

  **eseutil /d “D:\Exchsrvr\Mailbox Store (SERVER).edb”**
- Once defragment done, Mount & the Dismount the store immediately then perform below steps:

**Run ISINTEG:**

**isinteg -s (SERVER) -fix -test alltests**

[Refer Microsoft doc](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/repairing-exchange-databases-with-eseutil-when-and-how/ba-p/610276) & [Eseutil resources](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/168508-how-to-repair-exchange-databases-with-eseutil-when-and-how).